# В чем разница между VAR и OUT директивами Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Почитал что пишут по этому поводу и вот как понял:

Создаю объект

```
myObject := TObject.Create;
```

Посылаю в функцию как VAR параметр

```
MakeSomething(myObject);
```

Объект что был создан **не уничтожается**

```
function MakeSomething(var myObject: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  myObject := otherObject;
end;
```

В myObject присвоена ссылка на другой объект и в блоке кода вызываемом функцию будем работать с новым объектом, а ссылка на первый потеряна и произойдет так называемая утечка.

А если посылаю в функцию как OUT параметр

```
MakeSomething(myObject);
```

Объект что был создан **уничтожается** автоматом, без всяких Destroy или Free

```
function MakeSomething(out myObject: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  myObject := otherObject;
end;
```

И уже в "свободный" myObject помещаем ссылку на другой объект с которым будем работать в блоке кода вызываемом функцию

Правильно ли я понял? Если да, отличие только в этом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба способа передают аргумент по ссылке.

Для управляемых типов - строк и интерфейсов - при использовании `OUT` компилятор генерирует очистку параметра перед вызовом функции.
Код генерируемый для самого тела функции - **не должен отличаться** от того, что было бы с `VAR`
В примере для строки вызывается `@ULStrClr` **до** вызова Test
(это можно увидеть в asm листинге приCtrl-Alt-C на точке останова)

Для других типов, в том числе и объектов, очистка **не производится**, и `OUT` работает совершенно аналогично `VAR`.
Так что в примере с объектом старое значение **не** освободится.

```
procedure Test(out o: TStringList; out s: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(o.Count.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  o := TStringList.Create;
  s := 'q';
end;

var
  o: TStringList;
  s: string;
begin
  o:= TStringList.Create;
  o.Add('');
  s := 'pp';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Test(o, s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(o.Count.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);

pp  //строка до вызова

1   //список внутри функции 
    //строка внутри функции
0   //список после функции
q   //строка после функции
```